# Python mongodb create_index error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, unique-index

I am getting this error:

`Error: cache_for must be an integer or float.`

That is becouse of this line:

`self.db.table_name.create_index("url", {"unique": True})`

But i don't know why, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong the right syntax is:

```
self.db.table_name.create_index("url", unique=True)
```

By default this create a single key ascending index and is equivalent to

```
self.db.table_name.create_index([("url", pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)
```

To create a descending index you need to explicitly specify it:

```
self.db.table_name.create_index([("url", pymongo.DESCENDING)], unique=True)
```

More info in the [documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=create_index#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index)

---

You can also create more indexes with [**`create_indexes(indexes)`**](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=create_index#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_indexes)